# meteor nginx and the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, A circle here

Tags: meteor, nginx

here is the thing

everything works well before I use nginx.
on server, I deployed a mobile app server using mup, and after using nginx I got a

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http ://meteor.local' is therefore not allowed access.

and then I think I should add the header in nginx, so I add the following in nginx

> add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;

then I got

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http ://meteor.local, http: //meteor.local', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http: //meteor.local' is therefore not allowed access

and if I change the add_header with

> add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

then I got

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http: //meteor.local, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http: //meteor.local' is therefore not allowed access

I want to know how to fix this and what happens here.

btw, I have tried 
http://enable-cors.org/server_meteor.html, and I have  App.accessRule("*"); in my mobile-config.js

plus:

my server is deployed at 8001 port, but I got an info say that

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http: //my.site.com/__cordova/manifest.json

this file does not exist apparently, it locate at http: //my.site.com:8001/__cordova/manifest.json

my question is where send this request?

Comment: what Mobile framework are you using? Cordova?

Comment: yes, i use cordova, and if i connect the server directly in browser, it works well

Comment: Sorry I don't know so much about Cordova, but I have seen several questions related to Cordova and Access-Control-Allow-Origin like here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3469 and here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4132

Comment: thanks for reply, I have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

All things here is not about nginx, it's about the ROOT_URL of meteor app.
It can work well by setting the ROOT_URL with "http://my.site.com" along with the PORT env when you connect using browser, but if the client is cordova, you have to make your ROOT_URL "http://my.site.com:port"

Comment: Thanks for posting on how you fix it!